# unexpected ';', expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\

Tags: cakephp

Estaba practicando(aprendiendo) acerca de Cakephp, y en un tutorial de YouTube estaba siguiendo los pasos, pero me surgió el problema del título al intentar migrar (cake migrations migrate)

```php
<?php
use Migrations\AbstractMigration;

class CreateUsersTable extends AbstractMigration
{
    /**
     * Change Method.
     *
     * More information on this method is available here:
     * http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/migrations.html#the-change-method
     * @return void
     */
    public function change()
    {
        $table=$this->table('users');
        $table->addColumn('first_name', 'string', array('limit' =>100)
            ->addColumn('email', 'string', array('limit'=>100))
            ->addColumn('password', 'string')
            ->addColumn('role', 'enum', array('values'=>'admin', 'user'))
            ->addColumn('active', 'boolean')
            ->addColumn('modified', 'datetime')
            ->create(); //supuestamente aquí está el problema
    }
}
```

Comment: en esta línea `$table->addColumn('first_name', 'string', array('limit' =>100)` te falta un paréntesis al final de la misma:  `$table->addColumn('first_name', 'string', array('limit' =>100))`

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer te falta cerrrar un ) en tu primer addColumn

```
$table->addColumn('first_name', 'string', array('limit' =>100))
```

Comment: soy muy tonto c:, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: No pasa nada @teren, todos tenemos errores y estamos aquí para ayudar. No te olvides si ya te resolvió el problema, por favor haz click en el icono de la respuesta si ya se aclaró tus dudas.